# How to force attribute directive to wait for element directive to evaluate?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two custom directives define in my project:

- `<include-partial>` - element directive which gets template via `$http` service, compiles it and inserts into DOM
- `on-show="someFn()"` - attribute directive, which should call some function when the element becomes visible

I'd like to combine the two, so that I could write code like this:

`<include-partial on-show="init()">`

This, however won't work, as the content of `<include-partial>` is fetched asynchronously, so `on-show` has no DOM to attach to.

Do you have any ideas how to tackle this? How could I force `on-show` to wait until the `<include-partial>` is done compiling the DOM?

Thx in advance!

Comment: have u tried on load event with ng-include

Comment: I'm not using ng-include

Answer (score 0):

In your case "on-show" is never trigger because "include-aprtial" tag don't changes it's visibility. Try to hide "include-partial" in link function and show on content load.